# How to prove if $ f:A\to B$, then $ |A|\geq |f(A)|$?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I tried to prove by contradiction.

$|A|<|f(A)|$:

That mean the number of image element of set A is more than the set A, there will have two image elements of set A connect to same element of set A, contradiction with the element of domain can only connect to exactly one element to codomain.

Therefore,$|A|≥|f(A)|.$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes................

Comment: Yes, by the definition of a function every element in the domain maps to $\textit{exactly}$ one element in the co-domain.

Comment: some ideas:
g(x) = (x,f(x)) is bijection, if I is one-to-one then equality works, if f is not one-to-one, at least 2 elements share the same image, so there is an "extra" element in A than in B...but...are those sets finite or infinite? In general case you have to find a injective function from A to B or a surjective.

Comment: How do you define $|\cdot|\ge|\cdot|$? Apparently not by "there exists a surjection" ...